# Twig extract tranlations not working

Tags: php, twig, twig-extension

Am trying to extract PO files with using twig `i18` extension. Following this tutorial http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html i try to translate my site.

Problem is when i try to extract translations when i call in terminal:

```
root@debian:/var/www/html# xgettext --default-domain=messages -p ./locale --from-code=UTF-8 -n --omit-header -L PHP ./cache/*.php
xgettext: error while opening "./cache/*.php" for reading: No such file or directory
```

Check screenshot:
[image]

Checkig `$ xgettext --help` i dont see `-R` recursive search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to call `"./cache/*.php"` but your files are in subfolders, within the cache folder, so it should be `"./cache/**/*.php"`.

This command should work, I guess:

```
root@debian:/var/www/html# xgettext --default-domain=messages -p ./locale --from-code=UTF-8 -n --omit-header -L PHP ./cache/**/*.php
```

Comment: Yeah that is problem. I must learn more about linux recursive folders. Thanks you save me alot time